# Why is there a functional difference in HTML between block level and inline elements?

Tags: html, web-standards

*Note: I am NOT talking about the display - I understand why they have different defaults. I'm talking about the functional differences between blocks and inline elements, esp. in regards to things like nesting*

I've been told time and again that HTML is about describing content, what things do and what things are, not what they look like (beyond default stylistic elements associated with tags, that can be changed).

As such, it seems like the division between "block"-level tags and "inline"-level tags (not the display of those tags, but the inherent difference in those tags), something that trips up and complicated a great many neophyte and even more experience page designers, is arbitrary and... seemingly against principle, if you would. This sort of behaviour seems like something that should by controlled stylistically, not exist as a built-in element of a block. And in some ways, it IS controlled stylistically - we all know there is CSS that can make a span look like a div, and vice-versa.

So what is the point of having the functional distinction between blocks and inlines? Why aren't they just like any other nested element? Why isn't everything a "block" with "inline" elements simply set to "display: inline"? Is it just for, say, backwards compatibility, or is there a benefit to this seemingly arbitrary division that I'm just not seeing?

Note, this might be better as a community wiki question, since it's unlikely to have a single clear answer, but I'm not exactly sure on the details.

As an example, from what I understand, the following would be invalid html:

```
<label style="display:block">
 <h4>Name</h4>
 <span class='sub'>Whether legal, pseudonymous, or made up</span>
 <input id="name"></input>
</label>
```

Why?

Comment: Maybe that's the reason why this distinction does not really exist anymore in HTML5 http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/content-models.html.

Comment: HTML5 - Always finding new ways to make me both surprised and happy. I'm definitely gonna have to look deeper into that.

Comment: I think your question is better asked as *why is the distinction between block and inline considered to be so significant*. For example, the distinction between floating and non-floating elements isn't in question because no one is blowing its significance out of proportion... But why are the different settings for `display` considered *the* deciding factor as to how to describe an element?

Comment: There are also no rules that state you can't put divs in floats or vice versa, as far as I remember.

Comment: @GlyphGryph sorry, didn't see your comment on my answer until after I deleted it.  I did so after re-reading your posting and thinking to myself "no, there's got to be a better explanation than that."  Thus I deleted it in hopes of some better answer from someone more experienced than me. :\

Comment: It really is quite straight forward.  A block level element is defined as having a line break before and after. Block level elements include paragraphs, headings, lists, divs and other elemnts.  Do you really want to have to put a <br> before and after every paragraph?  No of course not, it is natural to assume there should be a line break before and after. 

I don't understand what you mean when you say "So what is the point of having the distinction between blocks and divs?" A div is a block level element.

Comment: Okay, people aren't really understanding my question, so I've tried to make it more clear.

Comment: @FelixKling - The names have changed, but "phrasing content" is essentially the same as "inline elements", only enforced more diligently than it was in XHTML.

Answer (score 0):

> Why isn't everything a "block" with "inline" elements simply set to "display: inline"?

Well, it almost kind of is; just the inverse.  Rather, everything is "inline" with "block" elements set to "display: block".

But that would be really annoying, if for every page you create, you need to tell it that `div` tags should be treated as block elements.  So for that reason, default styles are assumed, best illustrated at http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/sample.html